# Android Studio Regular Expression with regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to implement a regex but gives a problem with quotation marks.

My expression is: `\"[^\;]+\"`
and I try to implement:  `String Regex = \"[^\;]+\";` and gives an error.

Someone can help me?

Comment: What error do you get and could you add appropriate strings for the regexp?

Comment: please post full code

Comment: The errors are `error: unclosed string literal`, `error: illegal escape character` and `error: illegal character: '\'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but this line:

```
String Regex = \"[^\;]+\";
```

will never compile since it has several mistakes (you are placing `\` before fist quotation mark, you are escaping a semicolor for some reason and you are also escaping the final quotation mark). Maybe you want to do:

```
String Regex = "\"[^;]+\"";
```

but as I said, without knowing what you want to accomplish there's not much we can do.